# Is it acceptable to use yes as a question tag?

Tags: question-tags

I am aware that, for example, Russian and German speakers tend to use **yes** as a question tag (most likely because it is acceptable in their native language), as in

> You will come to the party, yes?

However, I was quite certain that this use was not correct English.

Today, while watching the movie Alien, I noticed that the science officer Ash repeatedly uses yes as a question tag, even though he does not have a particular foreign accent. Is this simply an artistic device, or is yes indeed used by native speakers as a question tag? If so, how colloquial is it?

Comment: It's used all the time.

Comment: It's probably more abrupt, less solicitous than the regular 'BrE' question tag: 'You're coming to the party, aren't you?' / 'You like tea, don't you?' It works well in factual situations: 'Seventeen seventeens are two hundred and eighty-nine, yes?'

Comment: Where I come from, in Pennsylvania, using that construction is like adding "**obviously**" to the end of the same words as if they were a declarative sentence. "***You will X, yes***?" means, "**You will X, obviously**. 

It is the same for the negative: "***You won't X, no?***" means, "You won't X, obviously." Asking the question is considered significantly more polite.

Comment: If we were asking a question and were acknowledging a choice, we would indicate our own preference, in the main question, and then indicate the choice in the alternate question. Except we use "won't you" and "will you" instead. "You ***will*** X, ***won't*** you? OR "You ***won't*** X, ***will*** you?" This is considered significantly more polite that the will/yes--won't/no construction.

Comment: It's not idiomatic -- probably a deliberate characterization device marking Ash's non-humanness.

Comment: The name Ash suggests Indian, not English.  The screenwriters probably intended the character Ash to not sound American.  Yes, it is a possible construction,  but not often used by native AmE speakers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the US we most commonly use *right* for that purpose:

> She's pretty, right?
>   That movie sucked, right?
>   You're an extraterrestrial, right?
>   It's really raining out there, right?

Using *yes* in these instances would indicate that you were not from our neck of the woods.

Comment: For the OP, to give the nuance, it is possible to say "..., yes?" or "..., no?", but it is not the preferred usage (which is, as you say, "..., right" or ..., isn't that so" or other tag question. Also, 'yes' or 'no' sound either impolite (too confrontational/presumptuous) or stilted or foreign.

Comment: In your part of the US "right" might be used for that purpose, but in others, "yes" might be more common.  In the Pacific NW I have heard it said "Really raining, yeah?"  I've also heard "right", but "yes" seems roughly equally likely here.  Go a little further North, and you might hear "Really raining, eh?"  In Vancouver, BC, for example.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the use of right as a simplified question tag compared to isn't it, etc. But I always associated "yes?" with nonnative speakers.

Comment: @Em1- Thanx for cleaning that up!

Answer (score 1):

We add question tags to the end of statements to turn them into questions. They are used in spoken language, especially when we want to check something is true, or invite people to agree with us.

Comment: While this is a true statement about question tags, I don't see how it addresses the question at all....